# Visual studio 2015 bookmark window not showing

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying the bookmark for the first time. I can toggle them on and use the hot keys to next and previous but cannot get the window to show. I used the menu to View bookmark window but not showing. Is there a trick to have the window that shows all the bookmarks ?

I read this article to find solution 
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42973/Using-Bookmark-in-Visual-Studio

Answer (score 0):

I did a window: Reset window layout and now the bookmark window shows.